# Direct mail (typo3) only content is send. Newsletter Layout not being send (page layout)

Tags: typo3, newsletter

When I am sending a direct mail newsletter as a test, everything looks fine. But when I am sending a newsletter to users only the content without my wrapping template is being send. The user see´s only the content elements in the newsletter. My html template is missing.

Answer (score 0):

By content, do you mean that users see only plain text? If so, it might be due to subscriptions preferences.

Based on your settings, both fe_users and tt_address may have a flag called "Recieve HTML mails" (can't recall the exact english version) which by default is not set.

Please let us know a bit more about your installation if this doesn't help :)

Comment: I know that for fe_users there is a checkbox "receive html mails" but for tt_address this checkbox is new for me. My E-Mail looks like this   <div class="csc-header csc-header-n1"><h1 class="csc-firstHeader">sdfasdf</h1></div>adfasdfasdf